# Post list not showing after embedding a post box

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a function `postEmbed()` to show a post box before displaying a post list, but nothing displays after `postEmbed()`. 
postEmbed():

```
function postEmbed() { 
if(empty($_SESSION['signed_in'])) {
    exit();
}
else {
echo '<div class="col-sm-4">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p>'; 
                echo '<textarea id="textarea" class="form-control" name="post_content" /></textarea><p>
        <h6 id="textarea_feedback" class="pull-right"></h6>
                    <input value="Create post" type="submit"  />
                 </form>
        </div>';
                 exit();
        }
$post_id = mt_rand(0,99999999);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, 'INSERT INTO topics(topic_id, topic_cat, topic_by, topic_body)
       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iiis', $post_id, $_GET["id"], $_SESSION['user_id'], $_POST['post_content']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/communities.php?id={$_POST['topic_cat']}", true, 302);
}
```

Post list (htm.php contains the function `postEmbed`):

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
require_once 'htm.php';
printHeader();
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, 'SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE cat_id = ?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if(!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo 'This community does not exist.';
        printFooter(); exit();
        }
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo '<div class="page-header"><h1>' . $row['cat_name'] .  '</h1></div>';
        echo '<h3>' . $row['cat_description'] . '</h3><br>';
    echo '<br>';

        $get_posts = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_cat = "'.$row['cat_id'].'" ORDER BY topic_date DESC LIMIT 50');

            if(!$get_posts || mysqli_num_rows($get_posts) == 0) {
                echo 'There are no posts in this community yet.';
            printFooter(); exit();
            }

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_posts)) {
                $get_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT user_name, user_id FROM users WHERE users.user_id = "'.$row['topic_by'].'" LIMIT 1'));
            echo'
        <div class="container">'
        postEmbed();
            echo '
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <header>
            <div class="panel-heading">' . $get_user['user_name'] . '</span>
            <span class="panel-heading">' . $row['topic_date'] . '</span>
            </header>';
        echo '
            <div class="panel-body">';
                        echo '<div id="post-content">
            <p id="p">' . htmlspecialchars($row['topic_body']) . '</p></div>';
                        echo '<a class="to-permalink-button" href="/' . $row['topic_id'] . '" data-pjax="#body">';
                        echo '</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>';

                }

printFooter();
?>
```

How the post list displays with `postEmbed()`:

[image: With]

How it displays without `postEmbed()`:

[image: Without]

`$_SESSION['signed_in']` is true, and there's no SQL errors.

This has been bothering me for a while, if anyone can solve this and give an explanation, I'd appreciate it a lot!

Comment: have you started your session? Where do you test for `$_SESSION['sigend_in']`?

Comment: `$_SESSION['signed_in']` is set on login, and destroyed on logout. If you're signed in, it displays "Signed in as (username)." on the top right corner, as shown in both images.

Comment: is this another script (the header)? Because you're not starting the session in this (shown) script!

Comment: or the other way: is it working as expected when removing the `if(empty($_SESSION['signed_in'])) {`?

Comment: Yes, that's the header. The session starts in connect.php.

Comment: btw: the `header(location..)` won't work, bacause you have output before that.

Comment: before `postEmbed();` there's a `;` missing at the end of `echo'<div class="container">'` (and there's no space after echo - don't know if that's critical)

Comment: I had already fixed that, sorry. Did nothing, still displayed the post box with nothing below it.

Comment: what if you `//` the header("location...")` ?  Could it be, that your server doesn't show errors (error reporting set to off), but still stops there? Because this would throw an error normally. [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Enabled error reporting, commented the header, nothing changed.

Comment: hm... still curious, but no real solution....    
What if you comment everything in `postEmbed` but a simple `echo "Hello World";`? (just trying to figure out where the problem is)

Comment: Tried that, nothing changed.

Comment: at least now we know, that the problem isn't in this function...

Comment: to be honest, my only left advise would be to strip it down to the minimum to find out where the problem is, I can't find it now. Comment everything that is markup, reduce it to logic.